# "preview": "quasar dev --mode preview" Unknown mode

Tags: vite, quasar-framework, quasar

1.I use the same method as the vue project to configure environment variables, but this doesn't work in quasar
2.I want to configure the command that doesn't work with the environment that doesn't work, but it doesn't seem to work
3. App • ⚠️  Unknown mode "preview"

ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.

In quasar, how to configure unreasonable packaging commands according to the environment